# Equivalent of JEditorPane.modelToView( ) in a JavaFX WebView

Tags: java, swing, javafx

In Swing, if I'm displaying text in a `JEditorPane` and I need to get the XY coordinates for a certain index within the text, I can use

```
Point p = jep.modelToView(idx);
```

, where jep is the name of my JEditorPane and idx is the int value of the index I'm interested in.

How can I do the same using a `WebView` in JavaFX?

Comment: you can use javascript if you want to bring some thing to the portview in webview of javafx , yourElement.scrollIntoView() is the method to use, to execute javascript inside the javafx you have to call its yourWebView.executeScript("your javascript goes here. .")